# Delete ParseFile

Tags: android, parse-platform, libgdx

Users can upload images to back end server. I want them to be able to delete and replace them. I've come to understand that I can't use the SDK to do this. So it's HTTP request.
This is what I've got so far. But I can't put it together and write the actual delete method.

```
private String parseURL = "https://api.parse.com";
private String appID = ".....";
private String parseAppID = "X-Parse-Application-Id";
private String masterKey = ".....";
private String parseMasterKey="X-Parse-Master-Key";
Net.HttpRequest http;

private String IMAGE1 = "***.png";
private String IMAGE2 = "***.png";

    http = new Net.HttpRequest(Net.HttpMethods.GET);
    http.setUrl(parseURL);
    http.setMethod("DELETE");
    http.setHeader(parseAppID,appID);
    http.setHeader(parseMasterKey,masterKey);
```

I've found working examples on JavaScript.

Comment: You cannot delete/remove files you upload to Parse directly. Just upload a new file and replace the file field with a newly uploaded file. To clean up any orphan files, you need to ask Parse to clean up for you from your application's settings menu on Parse dashboard.

Comment: @MoNazemi But according to this it seems I can actually delete it? https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#files-deleting-files Or have I misunderstood completely?

Comment: But that requires your master key which means you MUST NOT do it on any client under any circumstance as that will be a serious security breach. You must only rely on server side Cloud Code if you ever want to do this !

Comment: Ah I see.. and how would it be done using Cloud code? I can't seem to find any proper example of that either.

Comment: see an example of how to make a REST api in my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really have to do this, you can use the following **Cloud Code** to make a REST api call using your master key to delete a file:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/FILE.png',
  method: 'DELETE',
  headers: {
    'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'abcd1234',
    'X-Parse-Master-Key':     'abcd1234'
  }
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
  console.log(httpResponse.text);
}, function(httpResponse) {
   console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But this still put's my app in a security disadvantage? It would really benefit my app if the files could be deleted completely and not just replaced.

Comment: As long as your master key remains only on the server side, you should be fine.

Comment: Remember the script you put this into still requires that [you call the `success()` or `error()` callbacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34043227/383414)

Comment: Do I have to call some sort of save function after the script has returned success? Cause the file isn't being deleted though the script succeeded and I've checked the filename and everything seems to be in order.