# Parse Cloudfunction fails

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to delete a file through Cloud code.
But this script fails:

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("deleteFile1", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
       method: 'DELETE',
       url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/****.png',
       headers: {
        "X-Parse-Application-Id": "*******",
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" : "*******"
       },
       success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log('Delete succeeded  ' + httpResponse.text);
        response.success();
       },
       error: function(httpResponse) {
                response.error("failed");
       }
       });
});
```

with error 141, Script failure.

I call it like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("deleteFile1", map, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void done(Object object, ParseException e) {
            if(e == null){

            }else{
                System.out.println(e.getCode());
                utils.toast_error("Couldn't delete image.. try again");
            }

        }
    });
```

I've checked my Key's and they are correct. So the script itself must be wrong in some way. I thought maybe the url. Is /files suppose to be the ParseFile which the image file is bound to? I tried changing "request" & "response" to httpResponse etc. But it did no difference.

Comment: Hehe no problem! Yeah I saw that too, what's the main difference really?

Comment: [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/home) is basically just a much bigger, better, full featured version of Cloud Code. (In the same way a Mclaren P1 is like a newer, full featured Model T Ford...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated code** now runs properly at least, and you are able to catch the error.

You can *return the actual message* by modifying your error handler to return the `httpResponse.text`:

```
    error: function(httpResponse) {
        response.error("failed " + httpResponse.text);
    }
```

Initially, I was using the wrong `X-Parse-REST-API-Key` and getting the following error:

```
{
    "code": 141,
    "error": "failed {\"error\":\"unauthorized\"}\n"
}
```

Make sure to use the **MASTER** key: `X-Parse-Master-Key`. That fixed the code on my side and it runs fine.

---

**Original code** failed because you were not calling `success()` on your response when it has completed.

Below is the JSON response that is received when calling `/deleteFile1`; it shows that this is the problem:

```
{
    code: 141
    error: "success/error was not called"
}
```

If you look at the [Parse Cloud Code docs](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code) you will see that each method uses the `response` (or in your code, the `httpResponse`) parameter and calls `response.success()` when it has completed.

Always **read the response that Parse is sending back to you** - it may help to understand the error.

---

Found related post with answers that suggest the same thing:

- [Parse cloud code giving me Code: 141 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616799/parse-cloud-code-giving-me-code-141-error)

Comment: Please see my edit, my Log info tab on Parse.com now logs "failed" from the script.